# Import vCard or CSV to Google contacts via Google Contacts API version 3.0

Tags: java, gdata-api, google-contacts-api

Is there a way to import a vcard or csv file to Google Contacts?

Well, using the Java Api (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/) i can add single contact, but a whole file?

The GUI from Google Contacts supports such import features.

Any hints appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing they don't allow this since they had a paid service to sync contacts between outlook and google. If you can just import and export vcards using an API than ever programmer can write this syncing program easily.

I am also searching for a solution since this is exactly what I want to do but I don't like to pay to synch contacts.